# What will be the minimum value of the function?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $a, b, c, d$ be real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$. The task is to find the minimum value of $(a−b)(b−c)(c−d)(d−a)$ and what will be the value(s) of $(a, b, c, d)$
at this minimum.

I assumed $\sqrt{2}a=\sin x,\sqrt{2}b=\cos x,\sqrt{2}c=\sin y, 
\sqrt{2}d=\cos y$ and then opened the brackets but I wasn't able to solve by this approach as the expression was quite lengthy and difficult to solve. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: From which contest this problem was?

Comment: @Siddharth it was from my textbook which has questions from olympiads from previous years. But name isn't written here.

Comment: APMO 2022 P5, see: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2846808

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Min. $f(a,b,c,d)=(a-b)(b-c)(c-d)(d-a)$ sub. to $g(a,b,c,d)=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-1=0$. The method of Lagrange multipliers $f_i=\lambda g_i$, $i=a,b,c,d$ gives the system
$$\frac f{a-b}-\frac f{d-a}=2\lambda a\tag1$$
$$\frac f{b-c}-\frac f{a-b}=2\lambda b\tag2$$
$$\frac f{c-d}-\frac f{b-c}=2\lambda c\tag3$$
$$\frac f{d-a}-\frac f{c-d}=2\lambda d\tag4$$
If we add $(1),(2),(3),(4)$, we find $$a+b+c+d=0.$$ If we add $(1),(2)$ and $(2),(3)$ we find
$$\frac f{b-c}-\frac f{d-a}=2\lambda (a+b)\tag5$$
and
$$\frac f{c-d}-\frac f{a-b}=2\lambda (b+c)\tag6$$
respectively. Dividing $(5)$ by $(6)$, we find $a(b-d)=c(b-d)$ but this leads to no minumum. So, we conclude that in $(5)$, $b=-a$. Then $d=-c.$ Hence, the problem reduces to:
Min $f(a,c)=4ac(a+c)^2$ sub. to $g(a,c)=a^2+c^2=\frac12.$ We can use the same method, the method of Lagrange multpliers, to find the minumum value of this "new problem". [Wolfram Alpha did this.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Optimize%204ac%28a%2Bc%29%5E2%20subject%20to%20a%5E2%2Bc%5E2%3D1%2F2)

Hence the minumum value of OP's problem is $-\frac18$ achived at four different points and one of these is $(\frac{1+\sqrt3}{4},-\frac{1+\sqrt3}{4},\frac{1-\sqrt3}{4},-\frac{1-\sqrt3}{4})$.